# Multiple UITableViewCells different fields per row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 tableViews, the first only loads a list from an array. 
The other 1, show details per row. But it shows a crash report:

'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: Exception'

What seems to be wrong with my code? I want to show each row a different detail that came from the same sqlite row.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell;
     //tableView 1  
     if(tableView == self.cTableLabel)
     {
          cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"courseCell"];
          NSLog(@"Here.");
          Course *courses = [self.course objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          cell.textLabel.text =courses.cName;
          cell.detailTextLabel.text =courses.cSchool;
          return cell;
     }
     //tableView 2
     if(tableView == self.jTableLabel)
     {
          if (indexPath.row == 0)
          {
               cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobName"];
               cell.textLabel.text = _jDetails.jName;
          }
          else if (indexPath.row == 1)
          {
               cell=  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobEarnings"];
               cell.textLabel.text  = @"Job Earnings (per month): Php";
               cell.detailTextLabel.text = _jDetails.jEarnings;
          }
          return cell;
     }
     return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns the correct number of rows for your table.  I would think this would be it.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(tableView == self.cTableLabel)
    {
        return [self.course count];

    }
    //tableView 2
    if(tableView == self.jTableLabel)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise I would set a break point on `return 0;` or NSLog before it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because my guess is neither if block is hit and you are returning zero. Does it get triggered?

Edit - Ah, I think I see `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will return a nil cell if you haven't set one up yet.  Try using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` instead. This will always return a valid cell assuming you called `registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:` first.

Give this a shot:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"courseCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"JobName"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"JobEarnings"];

    //tableView 1
    if(tableView == self.cTableLabel)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"courseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Here.");
        Course *courses = [self.course objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text =courses.cName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =courses.cSchool;
        return cell;
    }
    //tableView 2
    if(tableView == self.jTableLabel)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobName" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = _jDetails.jName;
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell=  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobEarnings" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text  = @"Job Earnings (per month): Php";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = _jDetails.jEarnings;
        }
        return cell;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Also `registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:` could be called in your init, it only needs to be declared once.

Comment: Hmm.. So which return statement does it hit?

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, a table view's data source should generally reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. A table view maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.

If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different cells for each tableview, Try to use the above code:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell;
         //tableView 1  
         if(tableView == self.cTableLabel)
         {
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        else
        {
            for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
              NSLog(@"Here.");
              Course *courses = [self.course objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              cell.textLabel.text =courses.cName;
              cell.detailTextLabel.text =courses.cSchool;
              return cell;
         }
         //tableView 2
         if(tableView == self.jTableLabel)
         {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        else
        {
            for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
              if (indexPath.row == 0)
              {
                   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobName"];
                   cell.textLabel.text = _jDetails.jName;
              }
              else if (indexPath.row == 1)
              {
                   cell=  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobEarnings"];
                   cell.textLabel.text  = @"Job Earnings (per month): Php";
                   cell.detailTextLabel.text = _jDetails.jEarnings;
              }
              return cell;
         }
         return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check either one of your table is returning more number of rows in numberOfRowsInSection method . It might be that you haven't put check on this method as both of the table are returning different number of rows .